# ReactJS - How can I push a "link" object to an array with unique values via a for loop?

Tags: reactjs

**Question:** How can I push unique links to an array so each link has a unique number, created via a for loop?

I'm having trouble creating an array of unique links.
I've simplified the code below, but I want to have each link contain it's own unique "i" value.

When I run this code and render the links, all the i values are set to the length of arrayHoldingData, and not the individual i values.

Is there a way I can do this so Link 1 as i value 0, Link 2 has i value 1, etc...

```
var arraysLink = []

for (var i = 0; i < arrayHoldingData.length; i++) {
  arraysLink.push(<a href="/" value = {i} onClick={() => console.log(i)} > Click </a>)
}
```

I've looked around on Stack and I can't find a similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you add value to tag is wrong. You are pushing string to array and you missed to add quotes. other think is the way you added value attribute `value = {i}`, I think it wont work as expected, you need to add like `value = '${i}'`. Check the snippet and let know it solves your problem.

```js
var arrayHoldingData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var arraysLink = []

for (var i = 0; i < arrayHoldingData.length; i++) {
  arraysLink.push(`<a href='/' value = '${i}' onClick={() => console.log(${i})} > Click </a>`)
}
console.log(arraysLink)
```

Comment: Hi Akhil, thanks for that.

It's somewhat working but when I render the links they appear as strings. So the links are quite literally: 
`<a href='/' value = '0' onClick={() => console.log(0)} > Click </a>`, and are not clickable. I've looked around to convert this to a html link, but not really working.

Comment: @KuroGane does this solved your issue ??. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: Hi Akhil, so the solution sort of works, but as I mentioned above it's now literally a string when rendered on the page now, and not a link.

Comment: @KuroGane there is no attribute `value` to anchor tag. You can iterate `arrayHoldingData` and add anchor tag in dom, check the fiddle, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wjirtx

Comment: Ok, so that seemed to be the trick. Thanks a lot for the great help Akhil, very much appreciated.